# How to add id to Friendly_id slug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, seo, friendly-url, friendly-id

I'm interested in generating slug with both title and id. Otherwise, I would get errors like post collection route overriding single post route.

```
class Post > ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id [:id, :title], use: :slugged
end
```

```
resources :posts do
  get "videos", on: :collection
end
```

Slug "videos" would conflict with "videos" collection route.

Is it possible to generate an slug with id and title?

```
"#{id}_#{title}" # Friendly Id slug
```

Answer (score 0):

Friendly Id can not do that because it generates slug before save so it will not have id
https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/slugged.rb#L250

You may need to use `to_param` method to custom this:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  def to_param
    "#{id}_#{title}".parameterize
  end
end
```

But then you need to write custom method to find a record id, something like in your controller:

```
def show
  id = params[:id].split('_')[0]
  post = Post.find(id)
end
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. I doesn't help my problem at all.

Comment: it is used to solve conflict routes, I updated answer for your problem

Comment: I just wanted to know if it was possible to do it with friendly_id.